# How do Pause-able downloads work?

Tags: download, http, bittorrent

I use Internet Download Manager (IDM) for downloading data, and I have noticed that in it's download progress window, it shows whether or not a download is pause-able (resume-able). Typically, file-sharing sites do not allow the transfer to be resumed if the connection is broken.

So the question is this: how does this work? Is it some config that's done on the sever? How does this differ from torrent downloads, where the download is always resume-able.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From a coding perspective, a download is just a just a byte array included in the HTTP response stream.

The [HTTP 1.1 protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (see page 30) includes a field in the Header called 'Range', which allows the request to specify the byte offset and length of the response requested.

So in essence you can say, "give me the HTTP object at this URL, but I only want the 1024th - 4096th bytes of it". The client browser then appends the byte stream to the portion of the file already downloaded. The client can tell where it needs to resume simply by checking the length of the file already downloaded, and increments it to determine the required offset.

As to how your download manager can tell, it sends an HTTP "HEAD" request. If the response code is 206 (partial content), then the http stream supports resumption.

Comment: FTP is also a commonly used protocol for transferring files. It used to be the primary means, though now HTTP is probably more common.

Comment: FTP uses essentially the same construct, though I'd have to look up the specifics before I'd attempt to implement code that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

This could be handled using a [Persistent cookie](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/persistent-cookies-used-for.html), not to be confused with a [session cookie](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html)  or you can use [Viewstate] if the site is built on ASP.NET, however this is not a good practice. Frank Thomas has the best answer.

Comment: I am not sure the reason this answer was downvoted so I upvoted it.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I just confirmed some facts with our senior developer and he said you 'could' use a Persistent cookie or viewstate to store the byte array's index information used in tracking & resuming the download through a browser based downloader, however it wasn't a good practice. Typically, for large resumable files, such as an MS product, you would download a download Manager application and it would work just as you said. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: This answer appears meaningless. It's not a problem of determining how much of the file has been downloaded; the client knows this already. You can communicate that back to the server using a cookie, but there are far better approaches. Headers, GET or POST params, etc. The question is asking how the file transfer is resumed, not how to pass information to a server.

Comment: The OP asked how it works and I pointed him in the direction of Cookies so that he could do further research. There are a dozen different ways a developer could make a resumable downloader. I would have done it using cookies on the client to track the download status via a start-stop index and used C# on the backend to calculate how much was downloaded (from index X to index Y) and then resumed from Y. A desktop download manager does the exact same thing, only it stores its information in a text file or database. This isn't stackoverflow, I'm not writing source code.

Comment: @JoshCampbell, the problem is that your solution would work for only people using your specific client software and server software. There are standard ways of solving this problem, as Frank points out in his answer, and no need to custom-code one. Additionally, your answer does not point out the process by which some sites allow the OP to resume downloads, and so does not answer the question. That's why I commented.

Comment: I agree with your comment.

Comment: @JoshCampbell why would a download dumping server care about being persistent at all - cookies has very little to do with it - never have i seen a use of cookie, and I don't think most download mangers care about cookies at all ? they will never ask you to provide cookie to begin with.