# Is it possible to download an MKV file starting from half-way over HTTP?

Tags: download, http, wget, curl, matroska

I have an MKV video file that I need to download starting form half-way through. The video encoded as h264, the audio is encoded as AAC.

Normally HTTP downloads sequentially so if your download speed is quick enough you can watch it live during the download.

If I wanted to start downloading from part-way through the video file is this possible? With Curl or Wget etc?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1133356/432690

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This almost does it but I think I'm missing some data because the MKV file plays with only audio, I'll edit my question to refine my requirements

Comment: there is a lot to this. Modern video files use compressed stream formats that vary in their physical formats (which is what you are referencing when you use HTTP with a offset and range specified in the request. and the server supports `partial content`).  MKV is a container format, and may contain streams using a wide variety of stream codecs. if you want to learn a little more about HTTP download resumption, see my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/641957/171793